# Gatsbyjs + Netlify CMS how to embed audio as background music in blog article

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, netlify, netlify-cms

I want to embed a music as the background music into my blog and let it auto play.
I thought it could be easy, just type the html code.

I have a music hosted on One Drive and I inserted 3 pieces of code into my blog like below:

```
<iframe src="https://onedrive.live.com/embed?cid=xxxxx&resid=xxx&authkey=xxxxxx" allow="autoplay" width="98" height="120" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>

<audio controls="" autoplay="" loop="">
    <source src="https://onedrive.live.com/embed?cid=xxxxx&resid=xxxxx&authkey=xxxxx&autoplay=1" type=”audio/mp3″>
</audio>

<embed id="background-audio" src="https://onedrive.live.com/embed?cid=xxxxx&amp;resid=xxxxx&amp;authkey=xxxxx" autostart="1">
```

[image: audio]

iframe and embed tags look same, they look like the music icon on the right side of the screen shot;
audio tag looks like the one on the left side, but disabled.

Could anyone show me how to do it?

---

Update 1

This is what the Backend looks like:
[image]

Comment: Just to clarify: are you simply asking how to autoplay an audio in JavaScript? [Does this help](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Autoplay_guide)?

Comment: @RobinMétral nope, I know how to do it with JavaScript but I need to make it happen with Gatsby + NetlifyCMS at the backend when writing Blog. I will add a screenshot to demo what I mean.